# Sum of inverse of primorials: a counterintuitive result

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

If we iteratively remove the multiples of the succesive prime numbers from the natural numbers, starting from 2, i.e.,

$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  ...  \rightarrow$

$1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21,  ...  \rightarrow$

$1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25,  ...  \rightarrow$

we are consecutively removing fractions

$$\frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{1}{2·3}, \; \frac{1}{2·3·5}, \; \frac{1}{2·3·5·7},\;  ... $$

from the total amount of natural numbers. If we carry on infinitely, iterating for all the prime numbers, we end up removing a fraction

$$\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2·3}+ \frac{1}{2·3·5}+ \frac{1}{2·3·5·7}+ ...=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{n}\#}=0.7052301717918...$$
of the total amount of naturals, where $p_{n}\#$ represents the $n-$th primorial.
What seems strange to me is that this sum (the final fraction of removed natural numbers) is not equal to $1$: since performing the sieve above shown would lead to the removal of all the natural numbers (except $1$), one  would expect this to be the case.
Obviously there is something that I'm missing here, but I can't find an explanation.

Comment: Summing up fractions $1/x$ is something different than "Removing fractions from naturals". "Removing primes with your logic gives $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}=\infty$. What does that mean then?

Comment: The fractions of numbers that you remove are *not* the reciprocals of the primorials. When you remove the multiples of $5$, you remove $\frac{2}{30}$, when you remove multiples of $7$, it's $\frac{8}{210}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, that seems to be the case. Could you elaborate on how these terms are obtained? Thank you very much

Comment: After you have removed the multiples of the first $n$ primes, the fraction of numbers not yet removed is $$F_n := \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{p_k - 1}{p_k}\,.$$ Then the fraction removed as multiples of the $(n+1)^{\text{st}}$ primes is $F_n - F_{n+1} = F_n /p_{n+1}$.